Batch inference on model from model registry
I want to run batch inference on sagemaker orchestrated by Airflow using sagemakertransform operator using an existing model from model registry. For the operator it takes model name as input.
How can I provide my existing model from model registry as an input to get inference on?

Did you try using the modelName parameter in the config. I think this should pick the model from registry.
